# XNA with Winforms Mouse coordinates incorrect until window resized

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, xna, mouse

Well, here I am with a problem in my program. I'm embedding the XNA client in a Winforms application, and I'm using mouse event handlers to deal with the controls. However, I've come across a rather strange issue. When I first open my client, the mouse clicks register some way away from the mouse itself (in fact, this seems to be proportional to the Y axis on which the mouse is positioned. i.e. it is fine if the mouse is at the y-coordinate 0, but very far away at y-coordinate 500). This I could fix by finding an equation for the offset and applying it, but that's not enough, because the moment I resize the window, no matter by how much, the offset disappears and everything works as expected, even if I return the window to its original size.

To get the mouse coordinates, I'm grabbing the values from the MouseEventArgs passed to the event handler. I have no idea why this might occur. If anyone knows, I would be very grateful if they would give me a hint.

Comment: I fixed this by forcing the form into a maximised state after initialisation, but I would still be very interested to know what was causing it.

Comment: That is very strange. Are you running Windows at an unusual DPI? I'd ask if you were setting `Mouse.WindowHandle` correctly, but you're using events.